# Error in netbeans when try to run program: Truncated module-info.class

Tags: java, exception, netbeans

I'm using Apache Netbeans 9.0 on Linux Mint and Git. I have a java project called *PowerCal* and while trying to run it, I get the following error:

```
run:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: /<PATHTOMYPROJECT>/PorwerCal/build/classes
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Truncated module-info.class
/home/<myusername>/.cache/netbeans/9.0/executor-snippets/run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/<myusername>/.cache/netbeans/9.0/executor-snippets/run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I have no idea why this is happening, I ran this project before with no problems, but then I started creating some classes and after that I couldn't run it again. So I rolled the project back to the beginning, to the point it  was working, but now it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try a "Clean & Build"?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? There is a fix for an [InvalidModuleDescriptorException in Java 10](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8191439), though obviously that does not necessarily relate to your problem. As suggested in the previous comment, just select the project's node, right click and select **Clean and Build**. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: Thanks  @skomisa and a_horse_with_no_name, i tried Clean & Build, but instead of what skomisa said i went to  "Run/Clean and Build Project" in the menu-bar and it didn't worked. Then a followed what skomisa said, and it works!. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's good. **Run/Clean and Build Project** should also have worked, but if some other project was current then you may have accidentally rebuilt that one instead. Note that when you select **Clean and Build Project** from the **Run** menu, its menu entry gets modified to specify which project is being rebuilt. I prefer rebuilding by selecting the project node, since that way it's impossible to accidentally rebuild the wrong project.

Comment: Thanks, i suggest you that you post your comment as an answer, so i can mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is this:

> Which version of Java are you using? There is a fix for an InvalidModuleDescriptorException in Java 10, though obviously that does not necessarily relate to your problem. As suggested in the previous comment, just select the project's node, right click and select Clean and Build. Does that fix the issue? – skomisa