# Can't run JFrames

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, portability

I've recently had a lot of trouble with netbeans, I'm on a portable version now(Apache NetBeans IDE 11.2), with JDK 13.0.1 and whenever I try to run even the simplest JFrames they crash with this error:

```
C:\Users\banhi\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\banhi\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: -1073740771
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

All i did was to create an application without main, then created a JFrame in default packate(just to test) and added a button:

```
public class JFnis extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public JFnis() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(117, 117, 117)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(210, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(115, 115, 115)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(162, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFnis.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFnis.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFnis.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFnis.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFnis().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

- .java classes work fine
- Source/Binary and java platform are both set to JDK 13
- I can clean&build the project fine

Answer (score 1):

I run your code in my IDE - IntelliJ, 
it worked good:

[image: Your code by IntelliJ]

Seems something is wrong with your IDE configuration, maybe missing some environment variables, or try to recreate the project.

if you don't want to replace to another IDE, like Eclipse / IntelliJ, you can try follow solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524219/error-in-netbeans-when-try-to-run-program-truncated-module-info-class)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but finally when I tried 'clean and build' on the parent project, it got fixed.